# Editing nested, copied objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my data structure.  You can see that each house contains a variable length array of rooms, which are also objects:

**Data Structure:**

```
houses = [{      
    id: 1,
    age: 50,
    cost: 100000,
    rooms: [{
        id: 1,
        type: basement,
        sqft: 600,
    },{
        id: 2,
        type: bedroom
        sqft: 450
    }]
}]
```

I display this information in a grid using `ng-repeat`, each row has an edit button.  When the user edits a House, they see a screen were they can edit a Temporary Copy of the data, and there is a save button.  If they don't Save, I revert to the original data.  Once in edit mode on a House, they may edit and save individual rooms in a separate sub-screen.  I am not sure how to save this data properly.

Houses and Rooms have their own Save buttons.  If they save the room data, I must copy the temporary nested data onto the original room object, but I don't know how to access that object since they have been editing a temporary object.  Maybe they've changed some house properties but only hit Save on one of the rooms, so I can't just copy the entire temporary House object.

How do I access, for example, the original Room #2 once they press Save?  Is there a way I can use `$index` to make changes to my original data object?  I need to save rooms without also saving the base house object.  i.e. Only the nested object should be saved.

I don't know if I can use the `$index` because my data may also be sorted and filtered before the row is edited.

Comment: If you get data from server, Save the data to server. Otherwise, you will save it temporarily and on refresh you will loose the saved data.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and scalable solution will be, to add 'id' as a property for each room, doors, bathrooms or windows. Or just put 'index' as a property at the time you are iterating this object.

So, you will get id or index with the object which user cannot change and you can identify the correct object to overwrite.

Comment: Then I would need to loop through all of the houses or rooms to find the correct one, right?  Since it is an array, I can't look it up by the key.

Answer (score 0):

on the click of edit create the copy of the object

```
ng-click=edit(id)
$scope.edit(id){
var result = OriginalArray.filter(function( obj ) {
 return obj.id == id;
   });
$scope.copy=angular.copy(result [0])
  }
```

then use this object to edit data and once the editing is done and user will press save button copy back the object to rooms array;

```
result[0]=$scope.copy;
```

and you can't use $index over here because changes should be done in the original array.

Comment: Ok yes, I think I understand.  I just wonder how I would do this if the data was filtered because the selected index would be different than the index in the original data